# Nested routes with param and router refresh process

Tags: angular, angular-ui-router

I have the following routes definition:

```
{
    path: 'clients',
    loadChildren: () =>
      import('@app/domains/clients').then((m) => m.WebClientsModule,),
},
```

Then inside the WebClientsModule, I have the following routes definition:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: ClientsContainerComponent, // Where I render the clients list
  },
  {
    path: ':id',
    component: ClientDetailsContainerComponent, // Rendering a component with a mat-toggle-button-group which manages the switch between client details and client managers list
    children: [
      {
        path: '',
        component: ClientDetailsViewComponent, // Rendering the nested client basic info details view
      },
      {
        path: ‘managers’,
        component: ClientManagersContainerComponent, // Rendering the client managers list
      },
    ],
  },
];
```

The problem happens when I navigate to the client details: `clients/{id}` and after clicking the mat-toggle-button-group in the managers option, it navigates to the `clients/{id}/managers` but if I refresh the page when I’m stay in the managers view, it redirects to the `clients/{id}` basic info route.

How can I solve this issue maintaining the nested route? I want to allow to update both routes separately and avoid the managers to redirect to the client basic info one.

[image]

Comment: Can you share stackblitz?

Comment: Finally I solved it. I was navigating directly in the `client/:id` route during the initialization, then all the nested routes were redirecting there. I finally moved the navigation process to the parent route in order to avoid redirecting on refresh as soon you navigate to the nested routes.